# When I get into the loop they won't seem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

[Video reference of the tutorial at the needed excercise](https://youtu.beXGf2GcyHPhc?list=LLC4NoK0HlbFT2Igr4abnrxQ&t=1105)

I have been trying to follow a turtle guide for a pong game. It is really simple and I understand it totally. The one thing that fails is the ball movement, there is a definition of the ball and then the loop, when I get into the loop I wrote the same code and the ball doesn't move

It seems that I am messing with a character that I am not aware I just ask if someone could help me look at it. I will cut everything object related and leave only the ball

I have downloaded the .py of the tutorial, executed it and it works fine.I copied the specific functions and it won't work.

```
import turtle 
import os

#Aplication and screen setting
ventana = turtle.Screen()
ventana.title("A little pong game")
ventana.bgcolor("black")
ventana.setup(width=800, height=600)
ventana.tracer(0)

#This is the ball definition"
# pelota
pelota = turtle.Turtle()
pelota.speed(0)
pelota.shape("circle")
pelota.color("white")
pelota.penup()
pelota.goto(0, 0)
pelota.dx = 2
pelota.dy = 2


while True:
    ventana.update()

    # Move the ball (this should get the ball moving)
    pelota.setx(pelota.xcor() + pelota.dx)  #-> This isn't working for me
    pelota.sety(pelota.ycor() + pelota.dy)  #-> This isn't working for me
```

This is the full working code (the one that works if I copy paste)

```
import turtle
import os

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)


# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 0.2
ball.dy = 0.2

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    # Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)
```

I expect the ball to move but in my code it won't start moving.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering.

Isn't blitting this part?

 ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)

I am not familiarized with the concept. I will read about it in a bit.

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't relevant, I had it in my head that this was a pygame question, but it's clearly not! Blitting will be in the `wn.update()` bit :-)

Comment: I copy & pasted both of your code examples above and they both work.  One moves the ball much faster than the other, but both work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cdlane for testing the code! It made me debug other thing and I found it. It was this:

```
if pelota.xcor() > 390:
    pelota.goto(0, 0)
    pelota.dx *= -1

if pelota.xcor() > -390: # This little mistake was reseting the ball and I thought it wasn't moving at all
    pelota.goto(0, 0)
    pelota.dx *= -1
```